# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' of 'value'

Tags: string, exception, dart

I am completely baffled. I am essentially trying to do `foo["x"]="y"` and getting the most baffling of exceptions. I actually made a minimal working example, and I had to nest Maps and Lists for the thing to break. I have no idea what's going on.

```
Map fixprobset(Map P) {
  print(P);
  if(!P.containsKey("name")) {
    final foo = P["tileset"].join(" ");
    P["name"] = foo;
  }
  if(P.containsKey("children")) {
    for(var k=0; k<P["children"].length;k++) fixprobset(P["children"][k]);
  }
  return P;
}

void main() {
  Map problemset = fixprobset({
    "name": "Jingle Jangle",
    "children": [
      {
        "tileset": ["1","2","3"]
      }
    ]
  });
  print(problemset);
}
```

[Click here and gaze in wonder on the bafflement](https://dartpad.dev/5b1a5dbfcfd1e5c52da9be74445b31df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so now I understand what's going on. Objects have a `runtimeType`, and even though `P` has the unassuming type declaration `Map`, `P.runtimeType` could be e.g. `Map<String,List<String>>`. Once that happens, a `Map` can no longer store heterogeneous objects. Getting around this was quite hard for me, the type declarations `Map<String,dynamic> P` or `Map<String,Object> P` really don't help, the undesirable `runtimeType` is there to stay. I've filed this as a ["bug"](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/892) although perhaps it will be deemed a (mis)feature.

This [gist](https://dartpad.dev/d041fe1d97bf1f6a378a45bc81cb4f28) has the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You problems comes from the fact that your are fighting against the type system in Dart. As you have discovered, there are something about the runtimeType which seems to be automatically assigned to some other type than `dynamic`.

I have made this example which works:

```
Map fixprobset(Map<dynamic, dynamic> P) {
  print(P);
  if (!P.containsKey("name")) {
    final foo = (P["tileset"] as List).join(" ");
    P["name"] = foo;
  }
  if (P.containsKey("children")) {
    for (var k = 0; k < (P["children"] as List).length; k++) {
      fixprobset((P["children"] as List)[k] as Map);
    }
  }
  return P;
}

void main() {
  final problemset = fixprobset(<dynamic, dynamic>{
    "name": "Jingle Jangle",
    "children": <dynamic>[
      <dynamic, dynamic>{
        "tileset": <dynamic>["1", "2", "3"]
      }
    ]
  });
  print(problemset);
}
```

As you can see, the automatically assigned types comes from your input data which gets assigned types which makes sense at the start of the program. Your problem is then, that you don't wants this automatically assigned types but want to change them after creation. So you want to change a `List<String>` into a `List<dynamic>` but to do that, you need to create a new object since you cannot change the type of an object after its creation.

So my "solution" fixes this by setting the type at the time of the creation of the lists and maps in the input of the first call to `fixprobset`.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I think I knew about marking types like this, but overall I had this and other perverted runtimeType bugs related to jsonDecode, which I don't think I'll be able to force into giving me the types I want? In any case, I understand what's happening now.